# Knob - Fit text inside circle

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

I'm trying to fit the text inside the circle, in paticulary I'm trying to add some labels such as Hour, Minutes,..
 However I can't fit the text inside the circle; at this moment I'm using this inside the draw function:

```
$('body').append('<span style="font-size:'+this.i.css('font-size')+'" >'+this.i.val()+'</span>');
        var ph_len=parseInt($('span:last').width());
        $('span:last').remove();
        if(ph_len>=parseInt(this.i.css('width'))){
            var d=(((parseInt(this.i.css('width'))-parseInt(this.lineWidth))*parseInt(this.i.css('font-size'))/ph_len)).toFixed(1);
            this.i.css({'font-size' : d + 'px '})
        }
```

I'm also looking for a more elegant way to achieve this.
JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c963c/

Answer (score 2):

you can set font size in draw method of jquery knob.

eg:

```
$(".knobslider").knob({

    draw : function(){
         $(".knobslider").css("font-size","15px");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use css ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/c963c/2/))?

```
.seconds {
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: Because it is part of a plugin where the user can decide the size of each circle, so I should calculate the font-size for each one of them

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'draw': function() {
    $(this.i).css('font-size', '10px');//your size
  }
```